# Publishing Excel sheet for Post-Build Action in Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I am really new to Jenkins and not sure if it is possible to publish an excel sheet using the 'Post-build Actions' after a successful build. I see options for XML/HTML files but not for excel typed files. I am assuming its a special plug in for Jenkins however I could not find it through a google/stack overflow search. Is this even possible?

Comment: Where do you want to publish the file to? If you just want it to be available via the Jenkins web interface, you can archive the artifact, and the file will be shown on the build page. Otherwise, there are a lot of "Publish over..." plugins to upload the file elsewhere.

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue.Publish HTML plugin can not publish excel files